# Proving that $S$ is a subring of $\mathbb{R}$.

Tags: abstract-algebra, proof-verification

The problem:

> Prove that $S = \{x2^y:x, y\in \mathbb{Z}\}$ is a subring of $\mathbb{R}$.

My attempt.

Suppose that $a,b,c,d,e,q,r\in \mathbb{Z}$ such that $q = ab$, $r = b+d$, and $b \leqslant d$. Using the Subring Test:

Nonempty: $$(0\cdot2^1) = 0\in S$$

Closed under Multiplication: $$(a2^b)(c2^d) = ab2^{b+d} = q2^r\in S$$

Closed under Subtraction: $$(a2^b - c2^d) = (a-c2^{d-b})2^b$$ and let $u = (a-c2^{d-b})$ for $u\in \mathbb{Z}$. Then $$(a2^b - c2^d) = (a-c2^{d-b})2^b = u2^b\in S$$

Therefore, $S$ is a subring of $\mathbb{R}$.$\Box$

I am most unsure about subtraction. Should I do more to justify that $u$ is an integer?

Comment: Yes, what happens if $d=0$, $b=1$ with $c=1$? Then $u$ cannot be an integer, and you'll need a better argument to show $S$ is closed under subtraction.

Comment: Should I do cases? Or is there a simple way I am not seeing?

Comment: Cases could work

Comment: @B.Mehta Oh wait, $b\leq d$. So that counterexample doesn't apply.  Will I still need to do cases?

Comment: Ah, I didn't see that $b \leq d$. Then your justification for $u$ is valid, but you need to justify why you can take $b \leq d$.

Comment: Or, just assume $d\ge b $. (Without loss of generality, as you can always change the signs of $a $ and $c $.)

Comment: @B.Mehta Great! I will accept your answer if you post it.

Comment: Why is q=ab and not q=ac?

Comment: @Axion004 Oops. It is a typo.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Looks good to me, since $b \leq d$ (without loss of generality), $2^{d-b} \in \Bbb{Z}$, so $u=a-c 2^{d-b} \in \Bbb{Z}$.